# How do events work in Google Script in regards to getting data from elements

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

Question 1) When a button is clicked is it possible to use something like this (see code below)?

```
function Submit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var checked = app.getElementById("checkbox").getValue();
}
```

Question 2) When a label is clicked is it possible to use something like this (see code below)?

```
function LabelClick(e) {
  var LabelText = e.parameter.getText();
}
```

Sorry, this probably stupid, but I can't see to find any decent examples of this and can't seem to work this out from Google's documentation and I'm just getting used to google script too. If you have the answer I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not very far... but not close enough to get it working...

Ui element's value is sent to the handler function in a so called callbackelement that is added to the handler. This callbackelement may be a button, a label or, more easily, the parent widget that contains all the other widgets. These "elements" are in the "e" of the handler function and are identified by their **names**.
In the other direction, ie if you need to modify an Ui element from another function then you can get this element by its ID (`getElementbyId()`) and assign it a value just the same way as you'd do it in the UI definition function.

I copy/paste a sample code from another post to illustrate what I said, you can see the `e.parameter.chkmode` that holds the value of the checkBox and I'll add a Label to show the reverse process (the text is changed when the button is clicked).

Hoping I was clear enough,

```
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
//
function move() {
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle("move test")
       .setHeight(100).setWidth(400).setStyleAttribute("background-color","beige");
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   var next = app.createButton('next').setWidth('180');
   var chkmode = app.createCheckBox("moving mode (checked = up/dwn, unchecked=L/R)").setValue(false).setName('chkmode');
   var label = app.createLabel("test Label with text that will be modified on click").setId('label');
   panel.add(next).add(chkmode).add(label);
   var handler = app.createServerHandler('click').addCallbackElement(panel);
   next.addClickHandler(handler);
   app.add(panel);
   ss.show(app);
 }
//
function click(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var activeline = sh.getActiveRange().getRow();// get the row number of the selected cell/range
  var activecol = sh.getActiveRange().getColumn();// get the row number of the selected cell/range
  var label = app.getElementById('label');
  label.setText('You have clicked the button');
  var chkmode=e.parameter.chkmode;
  if(chkmode=="true"){
    activeline++
    }else{
      activecol++}
  var sel=sh.getRange(activeline,activecol);
  sh.setActiveSelection(sel);// make the next row active
  return app;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a UI and events tutorial, I recommend:

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/uiapp